# Bounding object with volumes casts shadows and causes artifacts

Tags: shadows, volumetrics

I'm making a scene and bounding boxes with volumes in them cast their own shadows instead of the volume shadows. I've tried setting "Shadow mode" to None, but it doesn't change anything. I'm using Cycles.
Can someone help me with making the volumes cast shadows or if they can't be made so at least help with disabling the shadows of the bounding object.

Screenshot of the problem:
[image: Screenshot of the problem:]

Comment: Could you embed your image using StackExchange's built in image embed tools instead of relying on external links to explain your problem?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it, now I've embedded it